# Problems with Google Reverse geocoding

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, reverse-geocoding

How to correctly and clearly identify the address (e.g. Paris. France) of the coordinates using Google Reverse geocoding? Somewhere locations are marked by type “locality”, somewhere “administrative_area_level_2”, somewhere “administrative_area_level_3” etc. Is there any method to clearly determine the town or village or if the person is outside built-up areas?

Example:
We send request:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=true&language=en&latlng=55.6844952,37.6118719
Look for the city and In most cases get the following:

```
"address_components" : [
       {
          "long_name" : "Moscow",
          "short_name" : "Moscow",
          "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
       },
…
},
    "place_id" : "...",
    "types" : [ "locality" ]
},
```

But sometimes
we send request:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=true&language=en&latlng=60.123062,64.78818
Look for the city and get:

```
"address_components" : [
       {
          "long_name" : " gorod Uray",
          "short_name" : "g. Uray",
          "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
       },
...
},
    "place_id" : "...",
    "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2" ]
},
```

How the app can determine that in one case city is “**locality**”, and in other case city is “**administrative_area_level_2**” etc.

Comment: Im not sure I understand your question. For geolocation I have had success using [Geocoder gem](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) I would recommend that.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, Moscow is a capital and political center, that is why it is tagged as political; Gorod Uray is a not a city but a larger secondary administrative area, so it is tagged as administrative area.

[This Type list](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#Types) from Google Maps API Places reference documents it clearly for the use of each type that composes the GeocoderAddressComponent object in searchResult.